# Should my custom RoleProvider throw an exception in AddUsersToRoles?

Tags: asp.net, exception, roleprovider

I'm implementing a custom ASP.NET role provider, and I'm wondering whether its `AddUsersToRoles` method should throw a `ProviderException` if a user passed in is already in a role passed in.  The default Microsoft SQL Server role provider `SqlRoleProvider` exhibits this behaviour, even though the [official Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.adduserstoroles%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't recommend it:

> Exception Details: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The user 'myTestUser' is already in role 'myTestRole'.

I think it would be useful for my provider not to throw an exception in this case but just to move on when a given user is already in a given role; that way the calling code doesn't need to worry about duplicates.  But could there be existing role provider-using code that relies on an exception being thrown in this case?  If there is, should it be doing so given that Microsoft themselves don't seem to recommend it?

If I do want to implement a method similar to `AddUsersToRoles` that doesn't throw an exception when a user is already in a role, I can see 3 alternatives:

1. Implement it as `AddUsersToRoles` and just have different behaviour from the default `SqlRoleProvider`.
2. Implement it as a new `EnsureUsersInRoles` method in my role provider class, and access it from my calling code using `((MyProvider)(Roles.Provider)).EnsureUsersInRoles()`.
3. Just implement it in a totally separate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going down route 2) that I proposed in my question; I implement a `RoleProvider` with some additional methods as well, and then use the cast `((MyProvider)(Roles.Provider))` to get access to my additional methods, one of which is `EnsureUsersInRoles()`, which has the non-Exception-throwing functionality that my calling code wants.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd conform to what Microsoft does.  It would be hard to rule out the possibility that something somewhere does require that exception to be thrown.

Comment: So what about being able to have a call I can use that doesn't throw the exception?

Comment: I was thinking about this. While I agree that pre-checking that your user isn't already in a role is extra work, I think the pattern in MS stuff is pretty clear:  "AddWhatever" throws an error if it can't add something. And on reflection I think this is good, because at least you know where you are, unlike with a "silent failure", which could be because the item was already added but could be because something is wrong. (see next comment)

Comment: If you need a method that adds if something is missing but doesn't throw the exception, consider calling that method "EnsureUsersInRoles". That way you'd get the behavior you want but wouldn't be introducing a method that broke the existing pattern.

Comment: And where would that method go?  No such method is in `RoleProvider`.

Comment: I think either options 2 or 3 (in your question modification, above) are good ones.  I actually kind of prefer 3 because I don't like to cast a base type to a more derived type to get additional features:  assuming you know what the actual type of an abstractly-typed parameter will always be is the kind of assumption that comes back to bite you.